# Changing the state of parent component inside a child

Tags: reactjs

I have started learning react and I couldn't find the answer for one of my questions.

Let's say I have a parent component called main where I have states and one of them is a counter.

Inside main i have a child component called secondary with a few buttons.

Is that possible to change state of the parent component using the function inside the child component?

If not, would Redux help to solve that task?

Thanks in advance for clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parent component can keep a state, initialized in the `constructor` like follows:

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { counter: 0 }
  }
  ...
```

Then, you want to create a method in `Main` that increments your state counter:

```
  incrementCounter = () => {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
  }
```

You can pass this function reference to a child component as a prop. So, you might see this in the `render` method of `Main`:

```
<Child incrementParent={this.incrementCounter} />
```

Then, in the `Child`, whenever you'd like, you can call `this.props.incrementParent()` - and this will call the function that was passed to it from `Main`, which will increment the state counter for `Main`.

**Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/13q00xznjj)** that shows all of this put together. In it, there is a parent container (`Main`) with its own state counter. There is a `Child` component which has 3 buttons. Each button click increments its *own* counter, but also *any* button click will increment the parent's counter.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a function that updates the parent state, and pass it down via props, context or redux if your particular app needs it.

E.g. Using React hooks

```
function Parent() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  const increment = () => {
    setValue(value + 1);
  }

  return (
    <Child increment={increment} />
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  const { increment } = props;

  return (
    <button onClick={increment} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = { counter: 0 };

  updateCounter = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
     counter: prevState.counter + 1
    }))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Text>{this.state.counter}</Text>
        <ChildComponent updateCounter={this.updateCounter} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (<Button onPress={this.props.updateCounter}><Text>{'Press Me!'}</Text></Button>)
  }
}
```

You should pass the function of updating your counter `updateCounter` from parent, pass that reference to `ChildComponent`

Answer (score 0):

You can update parent state by passing a function to the child component to update the parent.

Upon calling `updateCounter`function in the example, you can decrement or increment the value of `count` by supplying an operator in the function's argument which can be `plus` or `minus`

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 1
  };
  updateCounter = operator => {
    if (["plus", "minus"].includes(operator)) {
      this.state(prevState => ({
        count: prevState.count + (operator === "plus" ? 1 : operator === "minus" ? -1 : 0)
      }));
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <Child count={count} updateCounter={this.updateCounter} />
    );
  };
};

const Child = props => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => props.updateCounter("minus")}>MINUS</button>
    <button onClick={() => props.updateCounter("plus")}>PLUS</button>
    <h1>{props.count}</h1>
  </div>
);
```